# Using python socket.gethostbyname to accept multiple arguments in the command Prompt

Tags: python, sockets, command-prompt, hostname, nslookup

I have a text file with a list of about 50 hostnames and I am looking to script a way to run through them to get each associated IP address in the Command Prompt.

I thought pasting the hostname list in to the following code might be the easiest way but socket.gethostbyname will take no more than 1 argument at a time.

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname("***hostnames***")
```

Is there a way to work around this argument issue, or is there a way to have the hostnames read from the textfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest work around is to pass a filename and iterate through it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import sys
import socket

file_nm = sys.argv[1]
with open(file_nm, 'r') as f:
  for host in f:
    print socket.gethostbyname(host.strip())
```